# How can i update label name of full images in bulk using CSV upload

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, seo, labels

I need to update all label name of images, how can i do it by csv.

Answer (score 1):

You should you **data profile** magento 1.9.
There is option to update selected colunm on basis of sku / product id.
Also your csv column name should be **_media_lable**: Define the Label of that image

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948063/magento-import-product-images-media-via-csv

[Source](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/dataflow.html)
Up answer if it's work.

Answer (score 0):

You can update product image label using the **CSV** upload. Update the existing  products using the product sku and add the image label column in the **CSV.** to update labels in bulk. Same procedure as the upload product in bulk but avoid using extra columns which is not necessary. Also use the product update instead of replace existing product when uploading.

Comment: does right >>>>

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kDkQ6gH.png

Comment: Also add the store_id and category_id field before the sku column, no need of image column. You can check `csv` for the missing columns needed to update the product.

Comment: Where i can find store id, actually i have maintain single store, when i export products, there is no column name of store id , only _store column name have exit, and also no value for _store

Comment: when i export   [SYSTEM -> IMPORT/EXPORT -> EXPORT ] , i get _store and _category, there is no store id and category id

Comment: Keep this column as it is and try to import csv.

Comment: Could you pls share excel sheet screen shot, what i send prior.

Comment: Please update your question with  the full excel image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48378/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-nitin-pawar).